# WCF Error - Method Not Allowed

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, iis

When running the WCF test client and debugging the WCF service locally, everything works fine. After I deploy it to IIS on a remote server and then try loading it with the WCF test client I start getting "Object not set to an instance of object" errors. I added a try-catch to the service and the error changed to "Method not allowed".

I have been reading up on these errors all day and most posts relate to people using JSON or AJAX to access their WCF client. I have tried many of the suggested solutions, most of which were changes to web.config. I am simply accessing it using the test client at this stage, it will be consumed by a Winform application once proven to work.

The 2 methods exposed on the service both create connections to a SQL server on a different domain, although there is a trust set up. I am thinking this could be part of the problem.

My Service Interface

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMeterQueryService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<Meter> FindMeter(string mprn);
```

Implemented Service

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
public class MeterQueryService : IMeterQueryService
{
    public List<Meter> FindMeter(string mprn)
    {
        using (var da = new DataAccess())
        {

        var meters = da.GetMeter(mprn);
        da.Dispose();
        return meters;

        }
    }
```

App Config File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" />
  </system.web>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Tims" connectionString="hidden" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>
  <!-- When deploying the service library project, the content of the config file must be added to the host's 
  app.config file. System.Configuration does not support config files for libraries. -->
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TimsAPI.MeterQueryService">
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
          set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
          set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
          to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

web config file, site references the WCF service library.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="TimsAPI.MeterQueryService">
        <endpoint address="http://easvr33:1000/" binding="basicHttpContextBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="TimsAPI.IMeterQueryService" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="localhost" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="false" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Update

I recreated the WCF service as a WCF Service website, rather than a library and it all works now. Something weird between the 2 config files I think. I would still be interested to know why it never worked but I do also understand it may be hard to diagnose for someone without full access to the source

Comment: Enable WCF tracing to see what is going wrong.

Comment: I don't see the connection string in your hosting website web.config. If the service needs to access a DB using a connection string, the connection string needs to be in the web.config of the hosting application. Same goes for other configuration parameters you use in the service.

Comment: Ah, could be on to something then. The connection string is in the app.config of the service library which is consumed by the WCF site, I didnt think the site needed the cs too.  Will check that.

Comment: The config file being used by the service is the config file of the hosting application and not the `app.config` of the service.

Comment: I moved the connection string to web.config and right enough it works. Don't I feel a little stupid having wasted over a day with it! Move that into a solution and I will mark as the answer.cheers for your help

Comment: Don`t feel bad, I knew this because I myself and developers on my team have done this a million times :) Happy I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a WCF service is hosted via an IIS website the service `app.config` is not used and instead the hosing site's `web.config` is loaded. All settings needed for the service to work must be duplicated to the `web.config` of the hosting site.

Comment: I have a min wait time for applying bounty, I will stick it on tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

Might be an issue with serving the SVC to begin with.  From [here](http://utilicode.wordpress.com/?s=method+not+allowed):

> 1.Open your Virtual Directory’s Properties.
>
> 2.Go to the Directory tab.
>
> 3.Click Configuration.
>
> 4.Click Add…
>
> 5.Provide the following information:
>
> a.Executable: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll
>
> b.Extension: .svc
>
> c.Verbs: GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG

Comment: I have it deployed on IIS as a website. Should it be in an application or VD within a website?